# Is there a way to change log levels in AWS Lambda in .Net Core?

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda

I'm seeing a lot of logs like `START RequestId: blah`, `REPORT RequestId: blah` and `END RequestId: blah` for each call.  I would like to not see that in our logs as it is just extra noise that is not needed right now.  I've searched around and so far have not been able to find anything that works, has anyone else got this working?  Ideally I could control this based on environment but I would accept any option of not logging these events.

Comment: Unfortunately those aren't coming from your code, they come from the underlying infrastructure, and cannot be turned off.

Comment: Ah well, thanks for the quick response.  Here's to hoping they enhance this in the future!

Comment: I would be happy if they just allowed me to set the name of the log group, TBH.